# Reading From a Large Database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am writing an app where I need to load and read from a database. This Database is around 900MB. When I copy it into `\assets\databases` in my app directory a java heap space error pops up on android studio. I increased the heap space with `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m`. I also tried other solutions found on the web but my problem stuck. I also know that there is a limit on how big the apk file should be. This is probably causing the java heap space error since my database is to big to load as part of the apk.

What is the alternative to this? How can I read my database from an android app without the database being physically saved in the .apk file.

Here is the stacktrace of the build error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Java heap space

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Java heap space
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$10(OutputScope.java:241)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:236)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:197)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:181)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doFullTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:471)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:165)
    at com.android.apkzlib.zip.StoredEntry.read(StoredEntry.java:346)
    at com.android.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.onZipEntryOutput(SigningExtension.java:256)
    at com.android.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.access$400(SigningExtension.java:55)
    at com.android.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension$1.lambda$added$0(SigningExtension.java:164)
    at com.android.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension$1$$Lambda$378/1751952517.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.notify(ZFile.java:2099)
    at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.addToEntries(ZFile.java:1746)
    at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.processAllReadyEntries(ZFile.java:1687)
    at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.processAllReadyEntriesWithWait(ZFile.java:1708)
    at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.hasPendingChangesWithWait(ZFile.java:2517)
    at com.android.apkzlib.zfile.ApkZFileCreator.hasPendingChangesWithWait(ApkZFileCreator.java:180)
    at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.hasPendingChangesWithWait(IncrementalPackager.java:319)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:694)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.splitFullAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:522)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$$Lambda$327/1788085017.processSplit(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$6(OutputScope.java:186)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope$$Lambda$328/436614112.processSplit(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$parallelForEachOutput$7(OutputScope.java:203)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope$$Lambda$329/792075765.processSplit(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.lambda$null$8(OutputScope.java:225)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope$$Lambda$331/1881111235.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForAllTasks(WaitableExecutor.java:215)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:235)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(OutputScope.java:197)
        at     com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.OutputScope.parallelForEachOutput(Output    Scope.java:181)


    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

     BUILD FAILED in 3m 24s
```

Comment: use sqlite queries for that

Comment: Could you copy paste here the stacktrace ?

Comment: @ValentinMichalak Just added the stacktrace now.

Comment: @pskink stacktrace added.

Comment: hope this helps: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jobb.html

Answer (score 1):

Using rest api? To be serious it's REALLY rare case to have such a big db on every device, imagine you want to update application - user should re-download whole app each time.

If you need to have db that big on device you should have SQL scripts that you can download and execute on startup of application. This can solve the problem with update. But in any case you should have some web service.

Comment: So is it physically impossible to load a large database on android apk or is it possible just not practical? if its the latter than how can I resolve the java heap space error?

Comment: @user7331538 https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html states that you can do that in a very tricky way, but as you mentioned it's not practical. org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m in gradle.properties allowed me to build an app with 800mb file, so it's the only way if you're sure what are you doing

Answer (score 0):

As i Agree mostly with the previous answer, i can suggest a mixed approach based on the user experience:

- Any data you need to show on spinners, filters and other widgets that are used and need ultra fast response its better to have an in app database.
- Any data that is shown by a search/filter function or has large chunk of data it should be provided by an external entity (external bd connection, web_service, etc). You must know way to implement web database server in any of its forms. My suggestion MySql but that would require a hosting al least.

Having a big database would have a lot of "walls" of implementation that are bypasseable but requiere a lot of effort.